# How to show all validation error message using jQuery/Ajax/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I am using following Javascript code to validate a form:

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'form-validation.php',        
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : formData,
        beforeSend : function () {
            $("#form-submit").text('Validation...');
            $("#form-submit").prop('disabled', true);
        }, 
        success : function ( result ) {
            $("#form-submit").text('Send Message');
            $("#form-submit").prop('disabled', false);  
            for ( x in result ) {   
                alert('key: ' + x + '\n' + 'value: ' + result[x]);                  
                $("#formResult").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+result[x]+'</div>');
                if( result['error'] == false ) {
                    $("#formResult").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Your message has been sent. I will contact with you asap.</div>'); 
                    $('#contactForm')[0].reset();   
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.href = 'mysite.com/portfolio/contact.php';
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }

        }
    });
});
```

In form-validation.php page I have following code:

```
<?php

$formName       = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-name']);
$formEmail      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-email']);
$formSubject    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-subject']);
$formMessage    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-message']);
$googleCaptcha  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$secret         = 'my secret code';
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$googleCaptcha);
$responseData   = json_decode($verifyResponse);

$data           = array();
$data['error']  = false;

if( isset($formName, $formEmail, $formSubject, $formMessage, $googleCaptcha) ) {
    if( empty($formName) && empty($formEmail) && empty($formSubject) && empty($formMessage) && empty($googleCaptcha) ) {
        $data['msg']    = 'All fields are required';        
        $data['error']      = true;
    } else {
        if( empty($formName)) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your name required';
            $data['error']          = true;
        } elseif( strlen($formName) < 2 || strlen($formName) > 20 ) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your name should be 2-20 characters long';
            $data['error']          = true;
        } elseif( is_numeric($formName)) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your name must be alphabic characters';
            $data['error']          = true;
        }

        if( empty($formEmail)) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your email address required';
            $data['error']          = true;
        } elseif( !filter_var($formEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your email is incorrect';
            $data['error']          = true;
        }

        if( empty($formSubject)) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your message subject required';
            $data['error']  = true;
        } elseif( strlen($formSubject) < 2 || strlen($formSubject) > 500 ) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your message subject should be 2-500 characters long';
            $data['error']      = true;
        } elseif( is_numeric($formSubject)) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your message subject must be alphabic characters';
            $data['error']      = true;
        }

        if( empty($formMessage)) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your message required';
            $data['error']      = true;
        } elseif( strlen($formMessage) < 2 || strlen($formMessage) > 1500 ) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your message should be 2-1500 characters long';
            $data['error']      = true;
        } elseif( is_numeric($formMessage)) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Your message must be alphabic characters';
            $data['error']      = true;
        }

        if( empty($googleCaptcha) ) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Invalid captcha';
            $data['error']      = true;
        } elseif(!$responseData->success) {
            $data['msg']    = 'Captcha verfication failed';
            $data['error']      = true;
        }
    }

    if( $data['error']  === false) {

        $to = "mysite@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Contac Form- Creativeartbd.com";

        $message = "<b>$formMessage</b>";       

        $header = "From:mysite.com.com \r\n";       
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

        $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
        if( $retval ) {
            $data['msg'] = 'Your message has been sent. I will contact with you asap.';
            $data['error']      = false;
        } else {
            $data['msg'] = "Your message didn't sent";
            $data['error']      = true;
        }       
    }
}

echo json_encode( $data );
```

Now, I have following question:

1. If the form has any validation error it's showing the error message one by one instead of showing all. why?
2. The validation is starting from the last input field. I mean in my form I have 5 input fields which is name, email, subject, message, google captcha. Now the error message is showing from the google captcha, message, subject, email and name instead of name, email, subject, message, google captcha.
3. Now to re-validate the google captcha I am reloading the page after successfully submit the form. Is there any other way to re-validate the google captcha without reload the page?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically, the returning $data contains only "msg" and "error", then it could not represent for errors of all fields. You have to make the $data more informative. And that why the error is showing for the last one first.

Comment: @TuanDuong Thanks for your reply. Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Create an array of all errors and convert it into json and display all those messages from ajax

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed You have to return $data with fields-as-keys, then in the JS/HTML, you can on/off the errors based on that fields-as-keys. I will write the sample code as answer.

Comment: You should use framework

Answer (score 1):

This is because your data['msg'] is overwritting in multiple error case. 
Please return your message in this way in array..

```
if( isset($formName, $formEmail, $formSubject, $formMessage, $googleCaptcha) ) {
if( empty($formName) && empty($formEmail) && empty($formSubject) && empty($formMessage) && empty($googleCaptcha) ) {
    $data[]    = 'All fields are required';        
    $data['error']      = true;
} else {
    if( empty($formName)) {
        $data[]    = 'Your name required';
        $data['error']          = true;
    } elseif( strlen($formName) < 2 || strlen($formName) > 20 ) {
        $data[]    = 'Your name should be 2-20 characters long';
        $data['error']          = true;
    } elseif( is_numeric($formName)) {
        $data[]    = 'Your name must be alphabic characters';
        $data['error']          = true;
    }

    if( empty($formEmail)) {
        $data[]    = 'Your email address required';
        $data['error']          = true;
    } elseif( !filter_var($formEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $data[]    = 'Your email is incorrect';
        $data['error']          = true;
    }

    if( empty($formSubject)) {
        $data[]    = 'Your message subject required';
        $data['error']  = true;
    } elseif( strlen($formSubject) < 2 || strlen($formSubject) > 500 ) {
        $data[]    = 'Your message subject should be 2-500 characters long';
        $data['error']      = true;
    } elseif( is_numeric($formSubject)) {
        $data[]    = 'Your message subject must be alphabic characters';
        $data['error']      = true;
    }

    if( empty($formMessage)) {
        $data[]    = 'Your message required';
        $data['error']      = true;
    } elseif( strlen($formMessage) < 2 || strlen($formMessage) > 1500 ) {
        $data[]    = 'Your message should be 2-1500 characters long';
        $data['error']      = true;
    } elseif( is_numeric($formMessage)) {
        $data[]    = 'Your message must be alphabic characters';
        $data['error']      = true;
    }

    if( empty($googleCaptcha) ) {
        $data[]    = 'Invalid captcha';
        $data['error']      = true;
    } elseif(!$responseData->success) {
        $data[]    = 'Captcha verfication failed';
        $data['error']      = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahmad Let me try with this.

Comment: It's not working. When I submit the form the submit button is showing me Validating... No error message is showing.

Comment: well, now it's showing all message in the console log but now on web page. Is there anything in JS I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use array_push() to store error messages. Follow documentation 
   [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)
2. Try the answer in this question

   [How to Reload ReCaptcha using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371314/how-to-reload-recaptcha-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ahman's code, or using this sample code

```
$formName       = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-name']);
$formEmail      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-email']);
$formSubje    ct    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-subject']);
$formMessage    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-message']);
$googleCaptcha  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$secret         = 'my secret code';
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$googleCaptcha);
$responseData   = json_decode($verifyResponse);

$data           = array();
$data['error']  = false;

if( isset($formName, $formEmail, $formSubject, $formMessage, $googleCaptcha) ) {
    if( empty($formName)) {
        $data['form-name']['msg']    = 'Your name required';
        $data['form-name']['error']          = true;
    } elseif( strlen($formName) < 2 || strlen($formName) > 20 ) {
        $data['form-name']['msg']    = 'Your name should be 2-20 characters long';
        $data['form-name']['error']          = true;
    } elseif( is_numeric($formName)) {
        $data['form-name']['msg']    = 'Your name must be alphabic characters';
        $data['form-name']['error']          = true;
    }

    if( empty($formEmail)) {
        $data['form-email']['msg']    = 'Your email address required';
        $data['form-email']['error']          = true;
    } elseif( !filter_var($formEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $data['form-email']['msg']    = 'Your email is incorrect';
        $data['form-email']['error']          = true;
    }
    ....
}

if( $data['error']  === false) {

    $to = "mysite@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Contac Form- Creativeartbd.com";

    $message = "<b>$formMessage</b>";

    $header = "From:mysite.com.com \r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    if( $retval ) {
        $data['send-mail']['msg'] = 'Your message has been sent. I will contact with you asap.';
        $data['send-mail']['error']      = false;
    } else {
        $data['send-mail']['msg'] = "Your message didn't sent";
        $dat['send-mail']a['error']      = true;
    }
    }
}    

echo json_encode( $data );
```

In the JS part, you could parse the json, look into keys, then show the error for each field

Comment: I'm using Ahmed reply but it's not showing the validation message on webpage but I can see it in console log. I am using followiing js code:

Comment: for ( var x in result) {
    alert( result[x] );
    $("#formResult").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+result[x]+'</div>');
   }

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed: Ahmed code returns error message as array, you have to loop in result[x] to show the detail

Comment: If I use result[x] then it returns `true` not details!

Comment: Using x in my loop is getting the object property. I need to get the details like...0,1,2,3... as the return value is showing like that: `{0: "All fields are required", error: true}`

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed Because the result returns correctly, so you may look into how to fetch array/object in JS. You can test from Chrome console. :)

Answer (score 0):

**jquery: index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#formResult").html("");

        formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url : 'form-validation.php',        
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : formData,
            cache : false,
            beforeSend : function () {
                $("#form-submit").text('Validation...');
                $("#form-submit").prop('disabled', true);
            }, 
            success : function ( result ) {
                $("#form-submit").text('Send Message');
                $("#form-submit").prop('disabled', false);

                /* for(x in result['error']){
                    alert('key: ' + x + '\n' + 'value: ' + result['error'][x]);
                } */

                if( result['success'] == true ) {
                    //$('#contactForm')[0].reset();
                    $("#formResult").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+result['msg'][0]+'</div>'); 
                    //$("#formResult").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Your message has been sent. I will contact with you asap.</div>'); 

                    var i = 5;
                    setInterval(function () {
                        i--;
                        $("#counter").html("you'll be redirect in " +i+ " seconds");
                    }, 1000);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.href = 'mysite.com/portfolio/contact.php';
                    }, i*1000);

                }else{

                    for(x in result['msg']){
                        //alert('key: ' + x + '\n' + 'value: ' + result['msg'][x]);
                        $("#formResult").append('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+result['msg'][x]+'</div>'+"\n");
                    }
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status + "\n" +thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**form-validation.php**

```
<?php

$formName       = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-name']);
$formEmail      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-email']);
$formSubject    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-subject']);
$formMessage    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form-message']);
$googleCaptcha  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$secret         = 'my secret code';
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$googleCaptcha);
//$verifyResponse = '{"success":1}';
$responseData   = json_decode($verifyResponse);

$data           = array();
$data['error']  = false;
$data['success'] = false;

if( isset($formName, $formEmail, $formSubject, $formMessage, $googleCaptcha) ) {
    if( empty($formName) && empty($formEmail) && empty($formSubject) && empty($formMessage) && empty($googleCaptcha) ) {
        $data['msg'][]    = 'All fields are required';        
        $data['error']      = true;
    } else {
        if( empty($formName)) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your name required';
            $data['error']          = true;
        } elseif( strlen($formName) < 2 || strlen($formName) > 20 ) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your name should be 2-20 characters long';
            $data['error']          = true;
        } elseif( is_numeric($formName)) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your name must be alphabic characters';
            $data['error']          = true;
        }

        if( empty($formEmail)) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your email address required';
            $data['error']          = true;
        } elseif( !filter_var($formEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your email is incorrect';
            $data['error']          = true;
        }

        if( empty($formSubject)) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your message subject required';
            $data['error']  = true;
        } elseif( strlen($formSubject) < 2 || strlen($formSubject) > 500 ) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your message subject should be 2-500 characters long';
            $data['error']      = true;
        } elseif( is_numeric($formSubject)) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your message subject must be alphabic characters';
            $data['error']      = true;
        }

        if( empty($formMessage)) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your message required';
            $data['error']      = true;
        } elseif( strlen($formMessage) < 2 || strlen($formMessage) > 1500 ) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your message should be 2-1500 characters long';
            $data['error']      = true;
        } elseif( is_numeric($formMessage)) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Your message must be alphabic characters';
            $data['error']      = true;
        }

        if( empty($googleCaptcha) ) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Invalid captcha';
            $data['error']      = true;
        } elseif(!$responseData->success) {
            $data['msg'][]    = 'Captcha verfication failed';
            $data['error']      = true;
        }
    }

    if( $data['error']  === false) {

        $to = "mysite@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Contac Form- Creativeartbd.com";

        $message = "<b>$formMessage</b>";       

        $header = "From:mysite.com.com \r\n";       
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

        $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
        //$retval = true;
        if( $retval ) {
            $data['msg'][] = 'Your message has been sent. I will contact with you asap.';
            $data['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $data['msg'][] = "Your message didn't sent";
            $data['error'] = true;
        }       
    }
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```